# How to insert text in canvas like Paint app?

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

I want to let user add text in Canvas ,and write what he want to write ,and also dragging and resizing it exactly like how we add text in paint application. 
This is what I've tried using angular script ...but I don't want to write text in input text,also i don't want to resize it using input text and change font size ,I want something like box inside the canvas and write in it exactly like paint app. I've already solve how to drag it,so i only need now to resize it inside the canvas by mouse movement and also adding text inside the canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Meme Maker</title>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
<div id="canvas-container" ng-mousedown="mouseDown($event)" ng- 
 mouseup="mouseUp($event)" ng-mousemove="mouseMove($event)" >
   <canvas id="canvas">Your browser doesn't support canvas</canvas>
</div>
<label for="text-content">Text Content</label>
<input type="text" id="textWrite" name="text-content" ng-model="textContent" 
ng-change="redraw()" placeholder="Write your Text here">
<label for="fill-color">Fill Color</label>
<input type="color" name="fill-color" ng-model="fillColor" ng- 
change="redraw()">
<label for="font-size"></label>
<input type="text" ng-change="redraw()" name="font-size" ng- 
model="textFont" 
placeholder="Enter Text Size">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.'+
'com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.js"></script>  
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
var mouseDownX = 0;
var mouseDownY = 0;
var mouseDiffX = 0;
var mouseDiffY = 0;

$scope.xTextPos = ($('#canvas').width()/2)-80;
$scope.yTextPos = $('#canvas').height();
$scope.fillColor = '#000000';
$scope.strokeColor = '#000000';
var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();

$scope.redraw = function () {
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)";
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
drawImage();
if(!$scope.textContent&&!$scope.textFont){
  drawText('',26);
}else if(!$scope.textContent&&$scope.textFont){
  drawText('',$scope.textFont);
}else if($scope.textContent&&$scope.textFont){
drawText($scope.textContent,$scope.textFont);
}else if($scope.textContent&&!$scope.textFont){
  drawText($scope.textContent,26);

}
}

$scope.mouseDown = function ($event) {
mouseDownX = $event.offsetX;
mouseDownY = $event.offsetY;
}

$scope.mouseUp = function ($event) {
$scope.xTextPos += mouseDiffX;
$scope.yTextPos += mouseDiffY;
mouseDownX = 0;
mouseDownY = 0;
mouseDiffX = 0;
mouseDiffY = 0;
}

$scope.mouseMove = function ($event) {
if (mouseDownX != 0 && mouseDownY != 0) {
  mouseDiffX = $event.offsetX - mouseDownX;
  mouseDiffY = $event.offsetY - mouseDownY;
  $scope.redraw();
}
}

function drawText(a,fontSize) {
//textCtx.font = '50px "Droid Sans"';
ctx.font = ""+fontSize+"px Arial";
ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
ctx.fillStyle = $scope.fillColor; // line color
ctx.fillText(a,$scope.xTextPos + mouseDiffX, $scope.yTextPos +           
mouseDiffY);
ctx.strokeStyle = $scope.fillColor; // line color
ctx.strokeText(a, $scope.xTextPos + mouseDiffX, $scope.yTextPos +     
mouseDiffY);
}

function drawImage() {
 //draw background image
var newWidth = img.width / 2;
var newHeight = img.height / 2;
canvasContainer.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
canvasContainer.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
canvas.width = newWidth;
canvas.height = newHeight;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
//draw a transparent box over the top
//ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5)";
//ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
}

//drawing of the test image - img1
img.onload = function () {
 drawImage();
};

var imageUrl = 'http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_'
+'633/cy_0/cw_1725/ch_1725/w_720/APL/uploads/2014/11/too-cute-'+
'doggone-it-video-playlist.jpg';
img.src = imageUrl;

WebFontConfig = {
google: {
  //families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
  //families: ['Droid Sans']
  families: ['Yatra One']
},

loading: function () { },
active: function () { },
inactive: function () { },
fontloading: function (familyName, fvd) { },
fontactive: function (familyName, fvd) {
  drawText('',26);
},
fontinactive: function (familyName, fvd) { }
};


(function (d) {
var wf = d.createElement('script'), s = d.scripts[0];
wf.src = 'webfont.js';
s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})(document);

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please give us more detail and show us what you did so far?

Comment: @Pankwood okkey